# Is convex subdifferential always non-empty?

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ be a proper, convex and l.s.c. function on a Banach space $X$. The mapping $\partial f:X\to 2^{X^*}$ defined by
$$\partial f(x)=\{x^*\in X^*: (x^*, v-x)\le f(v)-f(x)\,\,\mbox{for all}\, v\in X\}$$
is called the convex subdifferential of $f$. I was thinking: what if $f(x_0)=\infty$? Since $f$ is proper, then there exists at least one element $v\in X$ such that $f(v)\neq\infty$. It follows that $x^*=-\infty$ for all $x\in X$ if I consider $\partial f(x_{0})$. Does it have any sense? Natural question emerges: is always $\partial f\neq\emptyset$?

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to consider the real case $X = \mathbb R$ first. Then, if $f(x_0) = \infty$ and $f(v) < \infty$, you never have
$$\mathbb R \ni (x^*, v - x_0) \le f(v) - f(x_0) = -\infty,$$
hence $\partial f(x_0) = \emptyset$.

Even if $f(x_0) \in \mathbb R$, the subdifferential might be empty, consider
$f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $f(x) = +\infty$ otherwise, at the points $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: OP is  asking : " is always $\partial f\neq\emptyset$? " the answer is positive for proper lsc , convex functions.

Comment: @nonlinearthought The counter-example works exactly the same way for $f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is convex (or for the even simpler choice $f(x) = -\sqrt{x}$ for $x\geq 0$, and $f(x)=\infty$ else).

Comment: @ChristianClason: Thank you for spotting the missing "$-$".

Comment: @ChristianClason  What I see here is that,  you and gerw couldn't understand the question yet !?  $\partial f$ is a set-valued function. $\partial f =  \emptyset$ means   $\partial f(x)  =  \emptyset$ for ALL $x \in X$.  $\partial f$ for the function $f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not EMPTY set valued function since $\partial f(0) =\{0\} $.

Comment: @nonlinearthought That's indeed one possible interpretation, but not the only one (and, in my opinion, not the most reasonable one) -- it might also be a simple typo. Why not ask the OP to clarify his question if you think it is being misunderstood?

Comment: @ChristianClason WHAT?  the subdifferential of the indicator function of $\{0\}$ is whole Space !!!!

Comment: @nonlinearthought Sorry, yes, that was nonsense. For any $f\in \Gamma_0$, the domain of $\partial f$ has to be nonempty, since it is dense in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @nonlinearthought In any case, I think it would be helpful to edit your answer to make your interpretation of $\partial f \neq \emptyset$ explicit. (And I'll stop spamming gerw's answer now, and clean up my comments after that.)

Comment: @ChristianClason  That's OK.  I don't care about  OP's interpretation of his/her own question. I answered the question itself. To me there is only one interpretation of this question which is what problem states. It clearly states:  is always $\partial f\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: @Redshoes Hi, I'm having a similar question and I see you mentioned "proper lsc, convex function" here. Could you have a look at my question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439354/if-a-function-is-convex-then-its-subgradient-set-is-non-empty and provide some guidance?