# Subdifferential of convex functions is nonempty

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

I read the counterexample in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292325/is-convex-subdifferential-always-non-empty?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, and I am wondering if it is possible to fix the statement in this way:

Given a convex function $f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ and $x\in\mathbb R^d$. If $x$ has a neighborhood such that $f<\infty$, is that true that $\partial f(x)\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: If $f$ maps from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R$, you have $f < \infty$ everywhere.

Comment: @gerw Right, the original question meant to say from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Here is an outline of the proof:

- $f$ is bounded from above by some constant $M \in \mathbb R$ on a neighborhood of $x$
- $f$ is (Lipschitz) continuous on a neighborhood of $x$
- $\partial f(x) \ne \emptyset$

The last step is the most delicate (requires some separation theorem), but should be covered in most texts on convex optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true.

The subgradient set $\partial f(x)$ of a (proper) convex function $f$ is not empty on the relative interior of its domain $x \in \textrm{ri}(\textrm{dom}f)$. A proof is given by Theorem 23.4 in [Rockafellar’s Convex Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691015866/convex-analysis) book.

Your neighborhood condition on $x$ implies that $x \in \textrm{ri}(\textrm{dom}f)$.